# How to show status bar on top of the app?

Tags: ios, flutter

In ios, I want to show Network, Wifi, battery on top of the app on the safe area. I tried adding a safe area on top but all it does is it adds a white patch on top.

```
return new SafeArea(
  top: true,
    bottom: false,

    child: WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: _onWillPop,
  child: new Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    primary: false,
    appBar: null,
    resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    body: new Padding(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      child: body,
    ),
  ),
),
);
```

Comment: specify some code pls

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine the icons are over there. But you need to change the theme of the status bar

in **main.dart**

you need to add

```
Future main() async {
   SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
      statusBarColor: Colors.white, // Color for Android
    //  statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark // Dark == white status bar -- for IOS.
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light // light == black status bar -- for IOS.
  ));
  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Comment: I was having another SystemChrome in another file which was causing some issue. anyway thanks